# How to find the surface area of the ellipse

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The cylinder with radius of 0.15m is cut at an angle (30 degrees). Would it be possible to find the area of the ellipse with just this information?

I attached a picture of it here: [PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lU7IC.jpg)

Comment: Presumably you are referring to a cylinder with a circular cross-section. In that case, the orthogonal projection of the ellipse to the cross-sectional circle has the effect of decreasing area by a factor equal to the cosine of the angle (in this case, 30º).

Comment: @DanAsimov, would it be safe to say Acircle=Aellipse(cos30)? I'm just wondering if this could be expressed in integrals

Comment: In fact, let X be any subset of a plane P such that X has a well-defined area. Call it area(X). Then after X is  projected perpendicularly from P to another plane Q making an angle of  with P, the projected image of X will after the projection have area in Q equal to the product area(X)∙cos(). (This is an extremely useful fact that arises over and over.)

Comment: Yes, that fact can be expressed in integrals, but why would you want to? There are two much simpler ways of calculating this, so why bother with an integral. First is the method Dan Asimov has described, second is to use the ellipse area formula $\pi a b$, where $a, b$ are the semi-minor and semi-major axes, These are easily calculated as $a = 0.15\text{ m}$ and $b = \frac{0.15\text{ m}}{\cos 30^{\circ}}$.

Comment: @PaulSinclair, I'm trying to do advance self study for my class this coming fall for Calculus 3, and this was given as part of the past questions. For all other questions, the equations were given, such as boundaries and equation of the surface. So this one is quite challenging.